# Computing 3↑↑↑3 (In Python)

Tags: python, memory, bigdata

I'm giving a presentation on [Graham's Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number) and I wanted to compute the first few ↑s (i.e. 3↑3, 3↑↑3, and 3↑↑↑3) to give them an idea of how huge it gets in such a short time. I wrote some naive/direct code in python, based on the definitions of arrow notation, shown below:

```
def arrow2(a,b):
    c=1
    for i in np.arange(b):
        c=a**c
    return c

def arrow3(a,b):
    c=1
    for i in np.arange(b):
        c=arrow2(a,c)
    return c
```

Although "long" integers (limitless) and numpy arrays (limitless) were used, naturally the code takes up far too much memory while running and will take a very long time to process. Is there a solution to this? (or does someone already know the answer?) Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with "big data" as it is commonly used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, I just want to flesh out a bit just *how* hopeless it is to grasp numbers of this size.

I assume you already know that

```
3 ↑↑↑ 3 =
3 ↑↑ (3 ↑↑↑ 2) =
3 ↑↑ (3 ↑↑ 3) =
3 ↑↑ (3 ↑ 3 ↑ 3) =
3 ↑↑ (3 ↑ 27) =
3 ↑↑ 7625597484987
```

So this reduces to studying the growth of `3 ↑↑ i`.  Let's see how that grows:

```
3 ↑↑ 0 = 1
3 ↑↑ 1 = 3**(3↑↑0) = 3**1 = 3
3 ↑↑ 2 = 3**(3↑↑1) = 3**3 = 27
3 ↑↑ 3 = 3**(3↑↑2) = 3**27 = 7625597484987
3 ↑↑ 4 = 3**(3↑↑3) = 3**7625597484987 = ...?
```

We're already beyond the limit of what's feasible to compute on most personal computers.

```
>>> import math
>>> math.log10(3) * 3**27
3638334640024.0996
```

That's the base 10 logarithm of `3 ↑↑ 4`, showing that the latter has over 3 trillion (decimal) digits.  Even with a custom encoding using 4 bits per decimal digit, it would require over 1.5 terabytes of disk space to store it - and very few computers have enough RAM to compute it in a straightforward way.

Then `3 ↑↑ 5` is in turn 3 raised to that multi-trillion digit power.  The words and notations we normally use are *already* inadequate to give any real idea of just how large that is, and there is no computer with enough RAM or disk space to deal with it.

And we're only up to `3 ↑↑ 5`!  There are still *trillions* of layers to go to reach `3 ↑↑ 7625597484987` = `3↑↑↑3`.  It's beyond human comprehension.  Although, yes, infinitely many integers are even larger ;-)

Comment: For some reason I already knew how ridiculously huge it is, but even then it never ceased to amaze me by how big it _actually_ is.

Answer (score 4):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation):[image]

Suppose you want to store this number (call it `N`) on a computer, i.e. in binary. This will require `k` bits, where `2^k ~ N`. That means `k` is itself extremely large (just compare `2^k` with the tower at the end), much too large to be stored on all the hard drives in the world.

Comment: Just noting that 3↑↑↑3 is so big we couldn't even store a significant fraction of its binary representation even if each electron in the universe could be used to store one of its bits.  Which is in turn inconceivably larger than all the hard drives in the world could hold.  There's just nothing in human experience that bears any meaningful relationship to numbers so large.

So, far a start, the OP should rewrite their code in C ;-)